# Client-side JavaScript CSV file generation and email attachment

Tags: javascript, android, ios, csv, email-attachments

I need to develop an application in Javascript/HTML5 which will run on mobile devices (iOS/Android). This application must run client-side only (no server interaction).  It must take in form information and generate a CSV file locally.  Once generated it should open the local mail client and attach the CSV file to the message.

Is this possible?  I have found information on how to do the CSV file generation, but they all end in invoking a dynamically created `a` link's `click` function - which would download the CSV file to the user's phone.  If this step could be automated to go directly to a new email message with the CSV file attached, that would be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a light-weight client-side CSV generator library that might come in handy. Check it out on https://github.com/lbrtw/csv

When in place, you simply generate and email CSV files on the fly using the `getFileContents` method and either `window.open` or `location.href = ...`, like this:

```
var propertyOrder = ["name", "age", "height"];

var csv = new Csv(propertyOrder);

csv.add({ name : "Anders",
          age : 38,
          height : "178cm" });

csv.add({ name : "John Doe",
          age : 50,
          height : "184cm" });

var fileContents = csv.getFileContents();
var link = "mailto:" + emailAddress + "?subject=CSV&body=" + fileContents;

// This action should open the default email app:
window.location.href = link;

// , and if that doesn't work, try this instead:
window.open(link);
```